# Angular: several multiple select boxes with duplicate options

Tags: angularjs

I have several multiple select boxes, and each box may have duplicate options. I need them to work so that if I select an option in one box, is the same option appears in other boxes, it also gets selected. I also need it so that if I select another option in another box, and there are duplicates, that they also get selected without losing previous selections.

For example, box **A** has **[a,b,c,d]**, box **B** has **[a,q,w,e]**, and box **C** has **[d,x,c,v]**. If I select **A.a**, **B.a** also gets selected. If I select **C.d**, **A.d** also gets selected.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created a small demo...See if it matches your requirement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selected1" ng-options="x for x in option1" ng-change ="fireEvent1(selected1)">
</select>

<select ng-model="selected2" ng-options="y for y in option2" ng-change ="fireEvent2()">
</select>

<select ng-model="selected3" ng-options="z for z in option3" ng-change ="fireEvent3()">
</select>

</div>

</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.option1 = ["a", "b", "c","d"];

        $scope.option2 = ["a", "e", "f","g"];

    $scope.option3 = ["e", "s", "p","q"];

    $scope.fireEvent1 = function(selected1){
        for(var i=0;i< $scope.option2.length; i++){
            if($scope.option2[i] == selected1){
                $scope.selected2 = $scope.option2[0];
            }
        }
    }

});
</script>
</html>
```